# Windows 7's blue screen at ntoskrnl.exe+0x6F980

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bsod

So I got my hands on a relative's PC, which started this week to repeatedly crash from blue screen (Error : "Stop f4"). The system would crash when programs where loaded, without any apparent logic.

To try to find the cause, I followed those steps :

- I checked the RAM's status with memtest, no error. There are two of them, I tried to unplug each one and see the result : still crashing.
- I made a chkdsk from Win7 install CD and it repaired quite a few errors. Now the system seems less unstable, so far I can run user programs without trouble, however using some of windows functionalities still causes the blue screens.
- I tried to use the "Repair bad sectors" tool from the hard-drive's property panel. But it always crashes at the same progression percentage, soon after the analysis starts.
- I activated the minidump generation and downloaded BlueScreenView and it seems the crashes always happen at ntoskrnl.exe+0x6F980. Alternatively are also mentioned once cdrom.sys and volmgrx.sys.

Minidump summaries :

https://mega.nz/#!PplhhRrA!oEaRX6XMHqYCB8q9U2mTqUALoqc7rUt59o3c91BFcsk

I'd like ideas of what step I could take next !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you make available a couple of the minidump files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that updating the harddrive drivers somehow fixed the problem.